# How to fix "Illegal Argument Exception" when creating an Elasticsearch index for a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm trying to integrate Elasticsearch in my rails application. The problem comes when I try to do an import on my model. **Video.__elasticsearch__.import.**

So, in rails console, I ran **Video.__elasticsearch__.import**. I get this error: 
**myflix_development does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it.**

I then ran **Video.__elasticsearch__.create_index!** and **Video.__elasticsearch__.create_index!(force: true)** and they both returned the same error of illegal argument exception:

```
 PUT http://localhost:9200/myflix_development [status:400, request:0.027s, query:N/A]
2019-06-08 11:18:29 +0800: > {"settings":{},"mappings":{"_doc":{"properties":{}}}}
2019-06-08 11:18:29 +0800: < {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."},"status":400}
```

I understand that I am supposed to create an elasticsearch index when I try to do an import but I'm getting this illegal argument exception which I am puzzled about

This is what I've done to set things up:

1) Included the gems in my gemfile:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
```

2) Included an initializer: app/config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client =
  if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
    Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['SEARCHBOX_URL']
  elsif Rails.env.development?
    Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
  else
    Elasticsearch::Client.new
  end
```

3) Included elasticsearch in my Video model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  index_name ["myflix", Rails.env].join("_")
  ...
end
```

4) Gemfile.lock

```
 elasticsearch (7.1.0)
      elasticsearch-api (= 7.1.0)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 7.1.0)
    elasticsearch-api (7.1.0)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-model (6.0.0)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 1)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (6.0.0)
    elasticsearch-transport (7.1.0)
      faraday
      multi_json
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**Edit** 
1) Attempted to do a manual mapping in my model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Elasticsearch::Model

    settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :title, type: 'text'
      indexes :description, type: 'text'
    end
  end
...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly define the document type that `elasticsearch-model` passes to Elasticsearch by setting `document_type`. For instance:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  index_name ["myflix", Rails.env].join("_")
  document_type "video"
  ...
end
```

What name you use is arbitrary. As long as it's not `_doc`, you shouldn't run into this error on v7 and up.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you have, I think you are using elasticsearch 7. The type `_doc` is specified in your index query but types are [deprecated since es7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html).

You can try to update your elasticsearch library to match es7 or as suggested in the error message, you can use the parameter `include_type_name` in the mapping.

Comment: Yes, I am using ES 7.1.0. I included my gemfile.lock file in my question. I guess there are a few things which I'm unclear:     
1) The type _doc is specified in your index query. 
- Where can I deactivate this type _doc in my index query? I did not specify anything when I'm trying to do an import.    

2) You can try to update your elasticsearch library to match es7
- I download ES7 straight from the website. Wouldnt it already be updated?   

3) you can use the parameter include_type_name in the mapping.
- Not sure how to do this. How do I create  a mapping manually and specify that?

Comment: I also actually downgraded my ES version to ES6. When I try to creat the index in rails console: Video.__elasticsearch__.import I get this error: Video.__elasticsearch__.create_index! Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"mapping type name [doc] can't start with ''_"}(underscore)],"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"mapping type name [doc] can't start with ''_"(underscore)},"status":400} I'm not even sure where I specified the mapping type name [doc] to start with an underscore.

Comment: Using ELasticsearch 6.0.1, I looked up how to do a mapping and I included the code in my original post. Despite doing that, I still get the same error of mapping type name [doc] can't start with ''"}] So sorry for throwing out so many additional comments! This problem is really bugging me

Answer (score 0):

The "illegal argument exception" is getting occurred because ElasticSearch engine is failing to analyze a reserved keyword. **Properties** is considered the root field inside the mapping section.Reform the request as below by excluding the "_doc" keyword :

```
PUT {INDEX_NAME} {"settings":{},"mappings":{"properties":{}}}}
```